# How to write these two equations?

Tags: equations

I am trying to write these equations in latex, however this `'` and this symbol `|` somehow don't work, can anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

This is the code I write:

```
\begin{equation}
   
    Target: 
    Q^' (s\mid)
\end{equation}
```

I got this equations:
[image]

Below are the pictures, which I want achieve in latex.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For example, `$Q'(s\vert\theta^{Q'})$`

Comment: See also \prime.  I forget whether or not it needs to be in a superscript.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you showed us what you're trying.  You should be able to get that output with a 6 line tex file.  How do they not work?

Comment: Regarding your edit: you can't have blank lines in an equation environment, and `'` doesn't need a `^`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upper half of the screenshot below shows what I consider to be a fairly close copy of the screenshot you posted. Note the use of `'` and `|`. No idea why you would have experienced problems with these two symbols.

That said, I think the two-row display you showed is lacking, typographically speaking. First, no effort seems to have been made to relate what goes on in the first line with what is shown in the second; this could be fixed easily by aligning the elements in the rows on the `:` symbols. Second, TeX and LaTeX provide a macro called `\mid`, which should be used instead of `|` when the symbol has the meaning of "conditional on" -- which I believe to be the case here.

The result of addressing these two issues is shown in the lower half of the following screenshot.

[image: resulting output]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for `'gather*' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman clone text and math font
\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\textit{Predict} : \mu(s|\theta^{\mu}) : \textit{Gradient update }\theta^{\mu} \\
\textit{target} : Q'\bigl(s|\theta^{Q'}\bigr) : \textit{Soft update }\theta^{Q'}
\end{gather*}

\[
\begin{array}{r @{{}:{}} c @{{}:{}} l}
\textit{Predict} & \mu(\,s\mid \theta^{\mu}\,) & \textit{Gradient update }\theta^{\mu} \\[0.75ex]
\textit{Target}  & Q'(\,s\mid \theta^{Q'}\,) & \textit{Soft update }\theta^{Q'}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do I do this if I want to put numbering after the equations? For example, : (1), (2)

Comment: @James - If you need 2 separate equation numbers, I'd go with the first approach and replace the `gather*` environment with a `gather` (note: no asterisk) environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

My advice is as follows.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{r @{{}:{}} c @{{}:{}} r @{{}{}} l}
\textrm{Predict} & \mu(s\mid \theta^{\mu}) & \textrm{Gradient update } & \theta^{\mu} \\
\textrm{Target} & Q'(s\mid \theta^{Q'}) & \textrm{Soft update } & \theta^{Q'}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `amsfonts` package is loaded automatically by `amssymb` -- no need to load it via an explicit instruction.

Comment: @Mico You are right. It's my personal habit to invoke the whole list of ams packages. :）